# Check length of value and if it is numeric

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to check if the value in a textbox is numeric:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.numeric = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.keypress(options, function (e) {
                // allow backspace and delete
                if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 0)
                    return true;

                //if the letter is not digit
                if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)
                    return false;

                // check max range
                var dest = e.which - 48;
                var result = this.value + dest.toString();
                if (result > e.data.max) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

When using on an input textbox element, I declare it as follows

```
$(input).numeric({ max: 999});
```

The problem is that it's working on input and checking that
value should be integer and not string.

But I need to change code that it will validate double as well.

So if I will insert 0.22 it will be OK, but if I will insert .22 
it will not populate the number.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work as you expected :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.numeric = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.keypress(options, function(e) {
                // allow backspace and delete
                if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 0) {
                    return true;
                }

                // allow float
                if (e.which == 46 && this.value.length >=1 && this.value.indexOf('.') == -1) {
                    return true;
                }

                //if the letter is not digit
                if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) return false;

                // check max range
                var dest = e.which - 48;
                var result = this.value + dest.toString();
                if (result > e.data.max) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/GuillaumeCisco/nGNxG/

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer and the comments (especially the accepted one):
[Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Otherwise, is it really necessary to check your value on every keypress?

Answer (score 0):

I tried debugging the code. You should require only update for '.'. ASCII value of '.' (dot) is 46. If you do below changes it will work !

1. Update `(e.which == 8 || e.which == 0)` with `(e.which == 8 || e.which == 0||e.which==46)`
2. You require to wrap input with quotes - `$('input').numeric({ max: 999});`
3. Test by alerting the value with the code `alert(parseInt($('input').val()));`

I saw above changes solves this problem :) Please, Let me know if it doesn't work :)

Comment: It's better. But script has several problems

Comment: The main problem that is value .22 allowed but should not

Answer (score 0):

It can be cumbersome to validate on every `keypress` event, and just returning false from a keypress doesn't let the user know why they're not allowed to input that key. You probably have the field marked as numeric in the label or something like that, but any extra help you can give to the user, even if the user is just yourself, can save a lot of annoyance down the road. What about something like this?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.numeric = function(options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.blur(function(e) {
                if (isNaN(+this.value)) {
                    $('<span class="error">Must be numeric</span>').insertAfter($this);
                } else {
                    $this.next('span.error').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

There's a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/LbCrg/).

Also, you'll need to add back your min/max check from the options. I removed that for this example's sake.

Finally, if you are going to be doing a lot of validation, you might want to use a validation library like [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

I followed solution suggested by @Guillaume. But I added additional condition

```
 if (this.value.length > e.data.maxLength)
            return false;
```

So the all code below

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.numeric = function (options) {

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.keypress(options, function (e) {

                // allow backspace and delete
                if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 0)
                    return true;

                if (e.which == 46 && this.value.length >= 1 && this.value.indexOf('.') == -1) {
                    return true;
                }
                //if the letter is not digit
                if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)
                    return false;

                // check max range
                var dest = e.which - 48;
                var result = this.value + dest.toString();
                if (result > e.data.max) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (this.value.length > e.data.maxLength)
                    return false;
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And to use it

```
 $(input).numeric({ max: 999,maxLength:4});
```

**maxLength - property indicates maximum input length**